# error function in lang sicp in DrRacket does not bound

Tags: racket, sicp

I use DrRacket 6.6 and use *#lang sicp* , everything looks good but the function error does not exist, it says:

error: unbound identifier in module in: error

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the sicp package does not include the identifier `error` so it is not a part of the language `#lang sicp`. The purpose of the sicp package is to give a R5RS namespace with some of the books special bindings in addition, however there is no mention of a procedure or special form called `error` in the book.

Under the standard language in DrRacket, `#lang racket`, and under the current standard Scheme, `#!r6rs`, `error` is a procedure which can be used to signal an error (called exception in R6RS).

**Adding only `error` from `racket/base`:**

```
#lang sicp
(#%require (only racket/base error))

(error "some error") ; error gets thrown
```

Comment: YES, I want to have some tweak about it , can it be import from somewhere?

Comment: i use (#%require racket/base), but it import others which I do not need,

Comment: If you look at the docs for `#%require`, you will see that you can use the word `only` in it. Give that a shot.

Comment: @LeifAndersen A good idea. I've added it. I wasn't aware that `#%require` was a primitive and different than `require` so I would have guessed `only-in`.

Comment: @Leif Andersen,it is the very method I am finding, thank you very much